# Co-dependence of parenting help

Tags: constraints, parent

I'm still new to Blender.

When I try to make a human's spine helper on my skeleton, I use multiple helpers, they take helper1 plus helper 2 to take the rotation of the bone.

On Maya I know that I could solve it easily by just making the bone boing parented to the helper, but I think Blender doesn't let me change de hierarchy of the skeleton this way.

I've tried to changing parenting, using many types of constrain, but the result is always the same.

Any idea about how to create helpers on the spine?

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell cause you don't give us so much info. What does "com" and "sem" mean ? As far as I know, in Blender you don't often use "helpers" (=Empties?)  to control a rig. Instead, you use specific Bones (you can assign them any look you want (in Bone Properties/Viewport display) so that may be confusing. Those bones are part of the armature, so that solve a lot of dependence problems.

Comment: "*Com*" e "*Sem*" means "With" and "Without" in Portuguese. In stack exchange mandatory language for all posts is English. Please avoid text inside images because it can't be indexed, searched for or fixed in case of mistakes.